# Issue with cookies in wp-login

Tags: wp-login-form

After I’ve switched the /wp-login.php standard login URL to a different alternative (lets say /wploginaccess) every time I input the login credentials it fails only once with the following message:

> Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable
> cookies to use WordPress

If I try to input login credentials a second time, it works well. It just fails the first time I try to login.

This happens me in the 100% of my sites. I remember a long time ago, this was solved by introducing something in wp-config.php that I can barely remember (like the login url with a global variable or something like that)

**UPDATE:**

I've found something extra weird.

If I login the error:

> Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable
> cookies to use WordPress

Appears as I mentioned before. But if I simply refresh the page, it goes straightly to the backend wp-admin interface. The login is being done successfully despite that error. But it simply doesn't redirect to wp-admin and throws that error.

If I logout and re-login, after first login, it works well. It just fails on first fresh login.

Comment: Do you mean COOKIE_DOMAIN and COOKIE_PATH? I'd use your browser debug tools to check the cookies it's trying to set and work out why they aren't being sent back to the page correctly.

Comment: @Rup, I've noticed that the cookie path that is "required"  for login is like /wploginaccess, the standard / is not accepted. Maybe with COOKIEPATH to /wploginaccess it could be solved?